# Problemas añadiendo librerias a un proyecto en C#

Tags: visual-studio

Buenas tardes estoy tratando de añadir una libreria a un proyecto pero me salta esta ventana:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> The select frameworks make this project incompatible with Visual Studio 2010

Estoy usando Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Eso no es ningún error, simplemente te esta indicando que si añades esas nuevas librerías, no podrás usar visual studio 2010 para desarrollar o usar ese proyecto.

Answer (score -1):

Tienes que instalar la ultima version(`update 4`) del visual studio 2013. Si no te funciona, repara el visual studio con el instalador. Reinicia la maquina si es necesario.